# How to run aws code-build through cli with S3 artifact detail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-codebuild

I am trying to trigger aws code-build using cli using below cmd but I am getting error.

Does anyone else know about the fix for this issue?

```
aws codebuild start-build  --project-name my-db-deploy --artifacts-override="{\"type\": \"S3\", \"location\": \"arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-4444442770/my-db-dev-deploy/BuildArtif/ZepddNIiV\",\"encryptionDisabled\": false}" --environment-variables-override name='environment',value='prod'--environment-variables-override name='delete_on_termination_db_ebs_volume',value='true'
```

Error:

> An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the StartBuild
> operation: Invalid artifacts: location should not have a forward-slash

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your `--artifacts-override` to separate the location and the path

```
--artifacts-override="{\"type\": \"S3\", \"location\": \"arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-us-east-1-4444442770\", \"path\": \"my-db-dev-deploy/BuildArtif/ZepddNIiV\", \"encryptionDisabled\": false}"
```

Based on [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68910586/how-to-run-aws-code-build-through-cli-with-s3-artifact-detail):

`--location`

> If type is set to S3 , this is the name of the output bucket.

--path

> If type is set to S3 , this is the path to the output artifact. If path is not specified, path is not used.